# mysql select where and with multiple same variables

Tags: mysql

I've got table with following columns:
`product_attribute_id,product_id,attribute_id,attribute_value`

The data in table looks like this: 
`0,1,1,something` 
`1,1,2,somethingelse` 
`2,1,3,somethingelses`

I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id = 1 AND attribute_id = 2 AND attribute_id = 3
```

I understand why this don't work, I simply need to get the id of product, which STRICTLY  has attribute_id 1,2,3, using `IN` is probably out of the question.

Is there any way in mysql to achieve this?

Thx for your time :)

Comment: You could use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: I really don't understand why IN is out of the question??? In will find all that have id of 1,2,3.....but you say because you want to select where 1 AND 2 AND 3, but how will it ever be possible that ONE ITEM can be all THREE????

Comment: Obviously it can, gordon linoff proved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  You are looking for all three attributes within a given product.

I like to address these with aggregation and a `having` clause, because this is the most flexible approach:

```
select product_id
from table t
group by product_id
having max(attribute_id = 1) > 0 and
       max(attribute_id = 2) > 0 and
       max(attribute_id = 3) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT product_id
 FROM table
 GROUP BY product_id
 HAVING sum(case when attribute_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
 AND sum(case when attribute_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
 AND sum(case when attribute_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE IN`..

Like so...

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id IN (1,2,3);
```

I don't understand why you say "IN is out of the question"  ??

You could also use `OR`,  like this...

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id = 1 OR attribute_id = 2 OR attribute_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR instead of AND

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id = 1 OR attribute_id = 2 OR attribute_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UNION

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id = 1
UNION
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id = 2
UNION
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id = 3
```

Comment: It works like `IN` or `OR` , that was not what i was lookin for